# Example data for Hive tutorial

Tags: hive, dataset

The original Hive tutorial available online refers to a dataset called "pv_2008-06-08.txt":

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial

And of course, it is referenced in dozens of tutorials all over the Internet. However, there is no way I can find the original data anywhere. Does anybody have a clue where is it?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public Go through this link

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure if your comment answers my question. Either you understood I'm looking for a generic sample dataset (which I'm not: I'm precisely looking for the referred pageviews) or I can find it in the list of links that you gave me and I cannot see it. Would you please be a bit more precise?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the given site, found that examples given in that site is outdated. Please use new link for more examples.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-UsageandExamples

**NOTE: Many of the following examples are out of date.  More up to date information can be found in the LanguageManual.**

If you are still interested in that dataset, suggest you to mail to the community to provide (please refer below link)

http://hive.apache.org/mailing_lists.html

Hortonworks datasets:

Recently I come across this Hortonworks datasets which can be used for creating database and queries in Hive and Pig.

https://app.box.com/v/hadoopcrashcoursedata

If you want to try with this dataset, here is the link for creating table using the above dataset

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_4

Comment: Thanks for the link Habi, but sadly my requested dataset is not there.